# Cardinality proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Suppose sets $A$ and $B$ are finite subsets of a finite set $U$.

Prove that

$$|A \cap B | \ge | A | + | B | - | U |$$

Any advice as to how I should approach this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The opposite of the usual typesetting mistake occurred here: \mid was used where | is appropriate.  Both that and the weird alternation in and out of MathJax resulted in lack of standard spacing.  I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Draw a Venn diagram.  There are four regions, $A$ only, $B$ only, $AB$ and neither.  Assign a variable to the cardinality of each one.  The sum of the four is $|U|$.  Now plug the variables into what you want to prove and you might find inspiration.

Comment: I started out doing this and ended up with $C \ge -C + D$ Where do I go from there? I'm not sure how this could prove the claim.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $C,D$ so can't comment.  Please define your variables.

Comment: My apologies. If I let the cardinality Set A=p  Set B=q AintersectB=r and U = p+q+r+s (s = outside region)

I end up with 

 r >= p+q - (p+q+r+s)

resulting in

r >= -r-s

Answer (score 0):

intuition hints:

1. what's wrong about simply adding the cardinalities of the subsets ?
2. how many elements would be involved in the error made by 1. ?
3. can you bound the number of elements from 2. ?